# Form elements flowing out of Modal & incorrectly aligned with each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a simple modal form that would allow a user to enter a recipe and corresponding ingredients. I'm doing it as an express app (so using Jade) but I have converted the Jade to HTML and made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wy18wdez/).

Strangely enough when running the app locally (accompanying screenshot)the alignment errors are different to the ones produced by the fiddle.

[image: local error]

Excuse the HTML mess, I'm new enough to it and guilty of throwing whatever looked reasonable in the docs together.

The modal body HTML (what I imagine to be the offending piece of code) is shown below

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <form id="submitRecipe" role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="recipeName" placeholder="recipe name" autocomplete="off" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-inline recipeRow">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="ingredient" placeholder="ingredient" class="form-control"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="quantity" class="form-control"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option>g</option>
              <option>tsp</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="add-row" type="button" name="add-row" value="Add row" class="btn btn-default"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wy18wdez/3/) applying James King's suggestion

Comment: Remember that in Bootstrap 3 the class hierarchy is container -> row -> col-* -> content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out all the `<div class="row">` and remove class="form-horizontal" from your form.

All the .row are giving you negative margins left and right, causing you to overflow the modal

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it